# How do iostream iterators work?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, iostream

From the Standard Template Library I came to know about the `istream` and `ostream` iterators. I can't understand how they work.

I also don't understand why they are used. Why are they useful?

Comment: +1 not so much for the question, but for whoever was the genius who came up with the idea of insertion & stream iterators. It's really incredibly clever.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stream iterators provide an iterator interface to the formatted extraction/insertion operations of iostreams. For example, consider the following:

```
std::vector<int> v;

for (int n; std::cin >> n; )
    v.push_back(n);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
std::vector<int> v(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 
                   std::istream_iterator<int>{});
```

Advancing the iterator performs one exraction, akin to `std::cin >> n`; if the extraction fails, the iterator assumes the singular state, which is also the state of the default-constructed iterator.

By their very nature, these stream iterators are *single-pass*, i.e. the weakest kind of iterator: You can only visit each element in the "range" once, and never go back; and two non-end iterators built from the same stream compare equal although that does not have any meaning regarding the dereferenced value. (But note that there's a curious lack of specificity as to whether the first extraction is ever attempted if you don't dereference the iterator ever.)

Just for completeness, output stream iterators can be used similarly to turn a stream into a "container", useful for algorithms that work with iterators:

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Ouput stream iterators perform their work when assigned to; the other operations are no-ops.

---

Interestingly enough, there isn't a stream iterator that wraps `getline`; people often write one themselves, because iterator interfaces are useful in many ways.

Answer (score 5):

Stream iterators allow you to use a stream as a source or destination for something like an algorithm that expects to use an input or output iterator.

They're used primarily to give a uniform interface to a basic capability, so you don't need (for one example) to create intermediate results in some collection in memory, then copy your data from there to an output file (and likewise with inputs).

As far as how they work, an istream_iterator normally stores one T object internally. When you create the iterator, it reads (or tries to) one T from the file with `stream >> value;`. `operator *` gives you access to that value. `operator++` reads the next value.

Likewise, an ostream_iterator writes an item to the file when you assign to it. Since the stream advances automatically, `operator++` normally doesn't really do anything (except return a reference to the iterator). If you really want to delve into the details (such as they are), you could take a look at the [`infix_ostream_iterator`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13176/489) I posted some time ago.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the stream iterators are not useful by itself. Having a set of algorithms operating on iterators make them useful.

Comment: Isn't it rather the case that algorithms by themselves aren't useful, but they only become useful once you have a set of iterators to work on?

Comment: This is kind of a chicken-egg situation.

Comment: @KerrekSB Or that way, sure (but the algorithms work with the concept of iterators)

Comment: @ZacHowland Fortunately, the egg already hatched from the chicken before algorithms arrived: pointers were readily usable with the algorithms and they turned out to be useful even without algorithms.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Yes and no.  What useful action would you do with a pointer that doesn't involve some processing (aka algorithm)? ;)

Answer (score 1):

As an example to demonstrate what Kerrek and Jerry have already stated:

Instead of writing something like this:

```
std::vector<int> vInts;
int n;
while (fin >> n) // where fin is an open ifstream
    vInts.push_back(n);
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < vInts.size(); ++i)
    cout << vInts[i] << endl;
```

`istream_iterator` and `ostream_iterator` allow you to write code that does the same thing in a single line:

```
copy(istream_iterator<int>(fin), istream_iterator<int>(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));
```

Which avoids the temporary storage and potential loop-condition bugs (e.g. if you were to write `<=` instead of `<`).

Since the standard algorithms use iterators, having iterators for `istream`s and `ostream`s allows for usage of streams with many common algorithms.